# HTML Entity ( Unicode ) Character UI Reference List

Tags: html, standards, special-characters

I find that I have trouble articulating this question, but it's something like this:

I'm looking for a list of html entities from the standpoint of UI and UX.  In other words, a list of all html entities and how it is appropriate to use each.  Some are obvious like `⋯`, but others less so, e.g. `⟿`.

I know that many of them are for math, engineering, etc., but many Unicode characters are used on websites to communicate something to the user.

Is there a standardized or agreed upon reference guide for which Unicode characters should be used in web design and what the characters should be used to represent?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342103/what-unicode-character-do-you-use-in-your-website-instead-of-image-icons

Answer (score 1):

Unicode characters can be used however you'd like. Other than symbols with specific historical meanings, there aren't any hard and fast rules for using them in design. Heck, the Unicode Consortium has been adding very un-mathematic symbols for some time now (ie. http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-candidates.html). I would say it's a safe bet to use whatever characters will serve your design the best.

Answer (score 1):

Many special characters have specific meaning and usage.

- You can [learn about the basic ones](http://www.creativebloq.com/typography/special-characters-121310119).

Comment: That's a pretty cool link - but obviously a little limited.